# Ошибка "module was compiled with an incompatible version of kotlin" при подключении "material" зависимости

Tags: android, kotlin, android-gradle, android-jetpack-compose

Хочу использовать xml верстку и Compose в одном проекте, посмотреть как они вместе сочетаются. Но есть проблема, когда я добавляю в зависимости

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
```

вылетает ошибка

> android material gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-common/1.7.10/bac80c520d0a9e3f3673bc2658c6ed02ef45a76a/kotlin-stdlib-common-1.7.10.jar!/meta-inf/kotlin-stdlib-common.kotlin_module: module was compiled with an incompatible version of kotlin. the binary version of its metadata is 1.7.1, expected version is 1.5.1.

Не могу найти место, где нужно поправить, чтобы проект собрался.

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id("kotlin-parcelize")
}
    
android {
    compileSdk 32

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId 
        minSdk 21
        targetSdk 32
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version
    }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
    }

    dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    def nav_version = "2.5.3"
    implementation("androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:$nav_version")
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.1"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.4'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:$compose_version"
    }
```

```
    pluginManagement {
repositories {
    gradlePluginPortal()
    google()
    mavenCentral()
 }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
}
}
rootProject.name = "Jetpack Compose Test"
include ':app'

// build.gradle (project)

buildscript {
 ext {
    compose_version = '1.1.0-beta01'
 }
}
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common 
 to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.2' apply false
id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.2' apply false
id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.5.31' apply false
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Как я понял, зависимость

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.7.0'
```

требует в build.gradle (project) установить

```
plugins { id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.21' apply false }
```

но тогда появляется другая ошибка с совместимостью compose. В итоге я оставил в проекте более старую версию material ->

```
    'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
```

теперь проект собирается, но когда дохожу до фрагмента compose с material компонентами ловлю краш

Comment: Какая версия Kotlin используется в вашем проекте? Покажите родительский `build.gradle` файл. Отредактировать вопрос можно, нажав на кнопку [править](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1481120/edit) под вопросом.

Comment: Сформулируйте ваш вопрос так, чтобы он был сфокусирован на одной проблеме. Если появилась новая ошибка, то заведите [новый вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) по новой проблеме. Приложите в новый вопрос все необходимые детали и текст ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение найдено. Оказывается каждая версия compose совместима только с конкретной версией Kotlin. Вот здесь есть [таблица совместимостей версий](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-kotlin?hl=ru)

Таким образом, если у вас версия Kotlin 1.7.20, нужно установить

```
compose_version = '1.4.0-alpha01'
```

Кроме того, у вас также могут возникнуть ошибки при использовании стилей, тем и компонентов из material. Я также заменил в themes.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Name" parent="android:Theme.Material.Light.NoActionBar">
```

на

```
<style name="Theme.Name" parent="android:Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

и в манифесте нужно также поменять тему для application и для activity на

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Name"
```

Answer (score 0):

В тексте ошибки сказано, что material-зависимость при компиляции использует версию языка Kotlin `1.7.1`.

Чтобы исправить ошибку, увеличьте версию Kotlin в вашем проекте с `1.5.31` до `1.7.20`:

```
plugins {
    ...
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.7.20' apply false
}
```

Comment: Сейчас еще студию обновил до последней версии, и в tools -> Kotlin-> kotlin plugin verison стала версия 213-1.7.20-release-for-android-studio-AS6777.52

Comment: Я обновил вопрос и добавил все gradle файлы, не могли бы вы подсказать где еще версию можно изменить?

Comment: Так как в Android Studio у вас используется плагин Kotlin 1.7.20, то и в проекте рекомендуется выставить эту же версию 1.7.20. Я обновил свой ответ.

Comment: Да, но тогда уже появляется другая ошибка This version (1.1.0-beta01) of the Compose Compiler requires Kotlin version 1.5.31 but you appear to be using Kotlin version 1.7.20 which is not known to be compatible.  Please fix your configuration (or `suppressKotlinVersionCompatibilityCheck` but don't say I didn't warn you!).

Comment: Этой ошибки не было в исходном вопросе, заведите новый вопрос. Мой ответ фиксит конкретную проблему, которая у вас была изначально. С проблемами, которые возникают после решения текущей, надо разбираться отдельно.

Answer (score 0):

Пока остановился на том, что не использую material компоненты. Вместо material button поставил просто button, теперь все собирается и не ловлю краши. Чтобы использовать xml внутри compose фрагмента нужно добавить зависимость

```
   implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-viewbinding:1.2.1"
```

Во фрагменте

```
   @Composable
   fun MyFragment(navController: NavController) {
       AndroidViewBinding(MyFragmentBinding::inflate) {
          // ваши функции с действиями над элементами из xml разметки
       }
   }
```